# const objects (like in C++) in C#

Tags: c#, c++, constants, readonly

Is there any better way to have C++-like const objects in C# than coding all checks by yourself?

I know, I can do this:

```
readonly Whatever a = new Whatever();
```

But that just stops you from reassigning `a`, it doesnt stop you from *changing* `a`:

```
a = new Whatever(); // nope
a.some_property = 5; // still possible, if property exists and has a setter
```

I dont want *all* `Whatever`s be constant (in the c-meaning), I just want some ones.

The tedious approach would be this:

```
public class Whatever
{
    private bool _isConst;
    private int _some_property = 0;
    public Whatever(isConst = false)
    {
        _isConst = isConst;
    }
    public int some_property
    {
        get {return _some_property;}
        set
        {
            if (_isConst)
                Debug.Assert(" ... ");
            _some_property = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

As the comments suggest that I didnt make myself very clear:

In **C++** and in *C#*:

***const** -> *readonly*

**#DEFINE** -> *const*

**const(*)** -> *???*

Comment: you can use the const keyword

Comment: @preciousbetine: no, you cant do `const Whatever a = new Whatever();`

Comment: You want sometimes have a const value and sometimes no in same class?

Comment: @KevinKouketsu No, I want (like in C) have constant objects and mutable objects from the same class. Preferrably without writing two classes or playing compiler by coding all what the compiler does with `const` (in C) in C#.

Comment: With properties you can declare public get {} private set {}.  Is that good enough?

Comment: @Wyck No: "I dont want all Whatevers be constant (in the c-meaning), I just want some ones."

Comment: @Wyck: What about making your `Whatever` class immutable, as Wyck suggests?

Comment: You can provide an interface that allows only read-only access to the object.  Consider [ReadOnlyCollection<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)  Then your access ("const" or not) is determined by which interface you have to the object.  Would that be ok?

Comment: Have you read the old article about [Immutability in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/)?  It might help you decide on an approach.

Comment: @Wyck according to the article, I need *Observational immutability:*. As I asked: C-like const (with perhaps some mutable fields).

Comment: Just stop treating C# like it is C++, it doesn't get you very far.  const in C++ has awful warts with const_cast<> and mutable and no actual enforcement at runtime and a significant number of programmers that gave up on it because they couldn't figure it out.  It was intentionally left out of the CLR and C#.  Lots of C# programmers live happily without out.  Well, all of them :)

Comment: I suppose you could define a struct (a value type) instead of a class and declare some instances of it readonly.

Comment: @HansPassant A surprising statement to me, but coming from you it must have merit. In my book const was a good thing, enforceability or not, because it states the programmer's intention. "FYI only." It's all the more important in a language like C# that passes *almost everything* (sans atomic and other trivial types) by reference, and lacks proper "copy constructor" support at the same time.